# How many similarity classes of $2 \times 2$ complex matrices are there such that $A^n = I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> How many similarity classes of $2 \times 2$ complex matrices are there such that $A^n = I$?

It means the matrix $A$ satisfies the equation $x^n - 1 = 0$ whose roots are the $n$th roots of unity each having multiplicity $1$. This implies the characteristic polynomial as well as the minimal polynomial of $A$ must be of the form $(x - \alpha)(x - \beta)$ where $\alpha, \beta$ are *distinct* $n$th roots of unity. Thus $A$ should be similar to a matrix of the form

$$\begin{bmatrix} \alpha && 0 \\ 0 && \beta \end{bmatrix}$$

Out of the $n$ roots of unity, we can choose any two (distinct) roots as $\alpha$ and $\beta$. So there should be $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ possibilities but the answer stated is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Could someone clarify this for me?

Comment: What prevents it from being $(x-\alpha)^2$? Allowing for this gives$$\binom{n}2+n=\binom{n+1}2$$as required.

Comment: This answer $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} $ can be contradicted by taking $n=1$, as we see there is identity matrix, making only one class. But $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} $  gives $0$.

Comment: @PeterForeman Because the multiplicity of each root of unity is at most $1$ in $x^n-1$? Thus, the characteristic polynomial can have a multiplicity $1$ for each $\alpha$ I think.

Comment: @S.D. The **minimal** polynomial must have multiplicity $1$ for each $\alpha$, but this is not true for the characteristic polynomial. In other words, you have forgotten to account for the multiples of the identity matrix.

Comment: @BenGrossman I'm a bit confused about this. Doesn't the characteristic polynomial have to divide $x^n-1$ which has only simple roots? I mean $x^n -1$ can be zero only if it is a multiple of the characteristic polynomial. Or does it just need to be a multiple of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @S.D. As I plainly said, the answer is no. It is indeed (only) the minimal polynomial that must divide $x^n - 1$. Consider what happens when we choose a suitable multiple of the identity matrix. What are the characteristic and minimal polynomials?

Comment: I get your point, thanks. Any multiple of the minimal polynomial is zero so $x^n -1$ must only be a multiple of the minimal polynomial.